# Where does gender attach in "brotherly/sisterly"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, kinship-terms, grammatical-gender

If Leia loves her brother Luke, does she feel *sisterly* love (because she is his sister) or *brotherly* love (because he is her brother)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

She would feel a "sisterly love" — the love of a sister — for her brother. A mother feels "motherly love" for her children, etc.

The reason for possible confusion stems from the use of "brotherly love" to describe in a general way the love of human beings for each other, similar to the way "mankind" also includes women.

Comment: To help alleviate the confusion, Leia would not feel brotherly love toward something with no gender. The one being love has no bearing on the term. Also of note, since we are talking about Star Wars, if you didn't _know_ you were siblings, would it still be sisterly love? /flamebait

Comment: @MrHen actually, my question was prompted by basically that question on scifi.se (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3013/did-leia-know-luke-was-her-brother-when-she-kissed-him/3017#3017).  I elected to use "sisterly", but I wasn't certain that I was right.

Comment: thanks! I should have thought of "motherly" love, which makes it much clearer (but didn't, obviously).

Comment: Which brings up a new questions for me: What kind of love does a child feel for its mother?

Comment: @deceze: "A child's love" is commonly used.